# Caption does not appear under a figure

Tags: rotating, landscape

I need to put into my thesis (portrait format) a figure in landscape format. I tried using `pdflscape` environment but it didn't work for me. Now I am trying to use `sidewaysfigure` environment. The figure looks good [image: Scheme] but there is no caption under it. Where is my mistake? And is there any other way to put my figure in landscape format?

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
   \includegraphics{d:/Thesis/Thesis_InLaTeX/thesis_1/Figures/Scheme1.pdf}
\caption{Scheme of Tengiz--Koargalzhyn depression.}
   \label{fig:scheme1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Update: new figure [image: Scheme1]

Comment: My impression is that the figure has a lot of white padding around it. Try putting it into `\fbox` (`\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}`) to see if it's the case.

Comment: Tried, thanks but now I have a box at/on left and bottom edges of the list and still no caption under it.

Comment: Can you add the picture you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclosing your graphics in `\fbox` shows that the image is surrounded by white space that is considered in the image size, so the caption *is* printed, but beyond the page limit.

You have to measure the padding and then do

```
\includegraphics[trim=4cm 8cm 4cm 2cm,clip]{imagefile}
```

where the dimensions are just a wild guess. They represent, in order, the amount of trimming at the left, bottom, right and top.

Comment: Brilliant! It works, thanks a lot! Trim=3cm 3cm 5cm 3cm

Comment: @Higgs Boson thank you! Now I have my heading on the page with the figure :)